# converting yargs to process.argv

Tags: node.js

my instructor wants me to use process.argv only so
how would i convert this

```
    yargs.command({
    command : 'add',
    describe: "Adding a Note",
    builder: {
        title : {
            describe: 'Note Title',
            demandOption: true,
            type : 'string'
        },
        body: {
            describe: 'Note Body',
            demandOption: true,
            type : 'string'
        }
    },
    handler: function(argv){
        notes.addNote(argv.title, argv.body);       
    }
})

yargs.parse();
```

into process.argv

because in my notes.js
i am using this code

```
const fs = require('fs');

const addNote = function(title, body){
    const notes = loadNotes();
    const duplicateNotes = notes.filter(function (note) {
        return note.title === title;
    });
    if(duplicateNotes.length === 0){
        notes.push({
            title: title,
            body: body
        })
        saveNotes(notes);
        console.log('\nNew Note Added Successfully!!!\n');
    }
    else{
        console.log("\nNote Title already existed!!!\n");
    }
}

const loadNotes = function() {
    try{
        const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('data.json');
        const dataJSON = dataBuffer.toString();
        return JSON.parse(dataJSON);
    }
    catch(e){
        return []
    }
}

const saveNotes = function(notes)  {
    const dataJSON = JSON.stringify(notes);
    fs.writeFileSync('data.json', dataJSON);
}

module.exports = {
    addNote : addNote
}
```

in the terminal i want to be able to type

node app.js read with the result of :
1: i should buy a boat.
2: i should take a nap.

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the app.js file is where you were trying to use yargs and you have notes.js imported to. process.argv will giv you an array with first two items being node path and your file path and then whatever arguments you pass. You can start by slicing process.argv to remove the first 2 items and then just assume the first argument will be title and the second body.

```
const args = process.argv.slice(2);

notes.addNote(args[0], args[1]);
```

Then you run node app.js 'my title' 'my body'

You can also play a bit more with this and do something similar to an actual CLI accepting arguments.

Let's say you want to actually have --title and --body as arguments and capture them regardless of the order. You can assume that whatever comes after --title will be the title and whatever comes after body will the body. So what you need to do is find --title in the args array, find what its index is and increment by one, then you will have what you passed. You can also make it required and return an error when it is undefined and even use shortcuts.

```
// We don't need to remove the first two elements since we are looking for
// specific values in the array.
const args = process.argv;
let titleIndex = args.findIndex(element => element === '--title' || element === '-t');
let bodyIndex = args.findIndex(element => element === '--body' || element === '-b');

// If these arguments are not found, it will return -1, so we are always expecting 0 or more.
if (titleIndex < 0) {
  console.error('Error: No Title provided');
} else if (bodyIndex < 0) {
  console.error('Error: No Body provided');
} else {
  const title = args[++titleIndex];
  const body = args[++bodyIndex];

  notes.addNote(title, body); 
}
```

With this you can run

```
node app.js --title 'My Title' --body 'My Body'
node app.js --body 'My Body' --title 'My Title'
node app.js -b 'My Body' -t 'My Title'
```